# Matrix Decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, computational-mathematics

We consider a symmetric, nonsingular matrix:
\begin{equation*}
H=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
0 & B\\
B^T & A
\end{array}\right]
\end{equation*}
Where $B$ has dimensions $m \times n$ with $m \geq n$. Give a backward stable finite (actually, it means we shouldn't compute the eigen value or singular value of $H$) algorithm computinf the factorization: $H=QMQ^T$. With $Q$ orthognal and $M$ has form:
\begin{equation*}
\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 0 & Y^T \\
0 & X & Z^T \\
Y & Z & W   \\
\end{array}\right]
\end{equation*}
Where $X$ is symmetric positive definite, $W$ is symmetric, and $Y$ is square and lower antitriangular.

I have been thinking about this problem for a long time but with no idea. I know that probably we need to use backward stable methods (like Householder etc.) to make QR decomposition to $B$. But I have no idea that how can we generate a positive definite part $X$ from the symmetric matrix $A$. Can anyone help me ?

Comment: How can we have $m\ge n$ and still $H$ is non-singular??

Comment: I mean, if $H$ is non-singular then $m$ must be _equal_ to $n$

Comment: Does $Y$ lower antitriangular (for a $p \times p$ matrix) means $i+j<p+1 \implies Y_{i,j}=0$ ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 0):

Consider an example:
$$
H = \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & -1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
$$
Since you cannot change the determinant by orthogonal transformation, it is not possible to get positive H(2,2) preserving the considered block structure.
So, I guess, you have missed the p.s.d condition on $H$ probably.